# Strange list behavior

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've got a list with paragraphs in it, yet it's displaying pretty weird in Firefox and IE.

My HTML is set up like this:

```
<li><p>content</p></li>
```

Not weird is it? The paragraph doesn't have a width and a little (left) margin assigned to it. When the margin is removed it still looks the same. It doesn't change either when I change the `list-style-position` back to `outside`...

This is how it looks:

[image: the list]

Anyone familiar with this problem and knows a fix? I'm desperate.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Why do you use `<p>` inside `<li>`?

Comment: @Clément I usually use `<p>` to format texts instead of my list elements.

Comment: @Clément If you add your post as answer I can set it as correct answer. The `<p>` tags were in fact causing the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `<p>` inside a `<li>` tag. Simply remove the `<p>`, and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Write like this:

```
p{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

Comment: If this didn't work, the issue is almost certainly that some other rule was setting different properties. Did you try setting this on an element, in your browser tools?